# Make Advanced Searches in SQLite Data Base

Tags: python, database, search, select, sqlite

I got and address book with names of people.
I use the following code to perform a search in the name column:

```
register = []
text = "{0}%" .format(self.lineEdit_6.text())
c.execute("select id, name from contacts where nome like '{0}'" .format(text))
for row in c:
    register.append(row)
    self.listWidget_4.addItem(str(row[1]))
    self.listWidget_6.addItem(str(row[0]))
if register == []:
    self.listWidget_4.addItem("No result")
```

The name column has the name and the surname ( like, John Smith)
The code above works fine when i don't remember the entire name but just the starting letters.
But I want that the results show all the matches, not only at the beginning of the names.
So, if I got 3 names (Simonne Welsh, Adam Loyd, John Smith) and a type the letter S it has to give the result of the names Simone Welsh and John Smith.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
    text = "%{0}%" .format(self.lineEdit_6.text())
    c.execute("select id, name from contacts where nome like '{0}'" .format(text))
```

(include the wildcard *before* the match string as well as after).

Also, please consider using (*note: corrected this syntax*):

```
    c.execute("select id, name from contacts where nome like ?", [text])
```

or

```
    c.execute("select id, name from contacts where nome like ?", (text, ))
```

which will:

1. Make your code safe from SQL injection attacks.
2. Correctly handle cases in which the `text` includes special characters, like a single quote (for instance, name of `O'Reilly`).

Comment: When I use the code you suggested it raises: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.

Comment: Try printing `text` and see what you get.  The error is telling you that your SQL includes only one parameter (the `?` character) but that `(test)` is being interpreted as something with three separate values.  Also, try `text` without the parens or in square brackets (as a list) instead of as a tuple.  As a tuple, it may be parsing the characters.

Comment: I tried this way too: text = "%"+self.lineEdit_6.text()+"%" The both prints return: %s% (s is the letter i type). It works when i use the format but not with the ?.

Comment: @LarryLustig it should be `(text,)`; note the comma.

Comment: @DanD. Yes, I left that out of the list of possible alternatives -- although I always use the list format instead of tuples, and that works without the extra required comma.  I'll update the original answer.